# Correcting mis-encoded incoming links with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, percent-encoding

We've started getting incoming links that are causing 404 errors because questions marks are being encoded as `%253F` and equals are `%253D`.

Is there any way of doing a 301 redirect in .htaccess, swapping these incorrect encoddings for the proper ones?